# lua modules - what's the difference between using ":" and "." when defining functions?

Tags: module, lua

I'm still playing around with lua modules and I've found the following "interesting" issue that occurs depending on how you create your methods / functions inside a module. 
Note the following code in a file called test_suite.lua:

```
local mtests = {} -- public interface

function mtests:create_widget(arg1)
 print(arg1)
 -- does something
 assert(condition)
 print("TEST PASSED")
end
 return mtests
```

Using the above code, arg1 is always nil, no matter what I pass in when calling create_widget().  However, if I change the definition of the function to look like this:

```
function mtests.create_widget(arg1) -- notice the period instead of colon
 print(arg1)
 -- does something
 assert(condition)
 print("TEST PASSED")
end
```

then, the system displays arg1 properly.

This is how I call the method:

**execute_test.lua**

```
local x = require "test_suite"
x.create_widget(widgetname)
```

Can you tell me what the difference is?  I've been reading: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModuleDefinition

But I haven't come across anything that explains this to me. 
Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: ECrownofFire - I've modified my post to include an example of how I call the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All a colon does in a function declaration is add an implicit `self` argument. It's just a bit of syntactic sugar.

So if you're calling this with (assuming you assign the `mtests` table to `foo`), `foo.create_widget(bar)`, then `bar` is actually assigned to `self`, and `arg1` is left unassigned, and hence `nil`.

```
foo = {}
function foo:bar(arg)
    print(self)
    print(arg)
end
```

Calling it as `foo.bar("Hello")` prints this:

```
Hello
nil
```

However, calling it as `foo:bar("Hello")` or `foo.bar(foo, "Hello")` gives you this:

```
table: 0xDEADBEEF (some hex identifier)
Hello
```

It's basically the difference between `static` and member methods in a language like Java, C#, C++, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using : is more or less like using a this or self reference, and your object (table) does not have a arg1 defined on it (as something like a member). On the other way, using . is just like defining a function or method that is part of the table (maybe a static view if you wish) and then it uses the arg1 that was defined on it.

Answer (score 0):

`.` defines a static method / member, a static lib, Which means you can't create a new object of it. static methods / libs are just for having some customized functions like printing or download files from the web, clearing memory and...

`:` Is used for object members, members that are not static. These members change something in an object, for example clearing a specified textbox, deleting an object and...

Metamethod functions(Functions that have `:`) can be made in lua tables or C/C++ Bindings. a metamethod function is equal to something like this on a non-static object:

function meta:Print()
    self:Remove()
end

function meta.Print(self)
    self:Remove()
end

Also, with `.` you can get a number/value that doesn't require any call from a non-static or static object. For example:

```
-- C:
int a = 0;
-- Lua:
print(ent.a)

-- C:
int a()
{
    return 0;
}
-- Lua:
print(ent:a())
```

same function on a static member would be:

```
print(entlib.a())
```

Basically, each non-static object that has a function that can be called will be converted to `:` for better use.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, if I want to keep the ":" I should make a "property" that accepts and assigns a value to "arg1".  is this correct?

Comment: where can i get some additional documentation on this?

Comment: @dot pull up the Lua reference http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html and search for 'self' the first hit explains this. The book Programming in Lua (PIL) also discusses this (see lua.org for how to purchase).